# Every non deterministic Turing machine has an equivalent deterministic Turing machine Formal proof

Tags: turing-machines, simulation

is there exist a formal proof for Equivalence of deterministic and non deterministic Turing Machine ? i read Martin Davis and Sipser's book and there is no formal proof

Comment: Of course there is! It's not hard, either; a good exercise. What have *you* tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Raphael i read their approach and searched in internet , what i found was a turing machine with 3 tapes that simulate what we want , it uses BFS to Acheive the goal , but i dont know how can i write it mathematical model

Comment: Why are TMs with three tapes a problem? They are equivalent to one-tape TMs; just append that proof if you want. I'm sure you can find formal proofs for both.

Comment: @Raphael  Simulating the nondeterministic TM N with a 3-tape deterministic TM D :
1-Tape 1 of D is initialized with a copy of the input tape for N and never changes after initialization.
2-Tape 2 of D has a copy of what N's tape would be at that point of the computation that is currently specified by tape 3
3-Tape 3 of D successively contains a sequence of numbers that represent every possible path through N.
Each path represents (part of) a computation in N
Each number represents a choice at a nondeterministic branch in the ocmputation

Answer (score 3):

There is a full proof in Hopcroft, Motwani and Ullman's Book (John E. Hopcroft and Rajeev Motwani and Jeffrey D. Ullman (2003). Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation). There is an outline of proof in the wiki: [Equivalence of DTM with NDTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine#Equivalence_with_DTMs).

Comment: i read that , i also see his course on coursera , but there is no formal proof , it just says the proof idea , i want to model it , Mathematical Model

Comment: John E. Hopcroft and Rajeev Motwani and Jeffrey D. Ullman, Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, Second Edition, page 341, Theorem 8.11. Read That, and even then if you do not understand it, you can tell me where you do not understand it and I may add a comment.